# Value cannot be null error in processing OData from Web API

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI method that returns OData:

```
[HttpGet]
public PageResult<Students> GetStudents(ODataQueryOptions<Students> queryOptions, string ClassId)
    {
        var allStudents = (from s in new OStudentContext(Convert.ToInt64(ClassId)).Student select s).ToList();

        var results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(allStudents.AsQueryable());

        return new PageResult<Students>(results as IEnumerable<Students>, Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());

    }
```

The request URL is like so:

```
http://localhost:3333/api/odata/GetStudents?StudentId=40932&$inlinecount=allpages&$filter=((IsDeleted%20eq%20null)or(IsDeleted%20eq%20false))&$select=StudentId,FirstName,LastName,EmailID
```

The value in results is there and I can see the records returned. The count is actually 7 to be precise.

The problem is the the return statement throws this exception:

> Value cannot be null.Parameter name: data

Request.GetNextPageLink() is null as there is no next page link.

Request.GetInlineCount() is 7.

So what is null & what does the error mean about data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The element type after applying ODataQueryOptions is no longer Students if there is some $select or $expand.

It changes to SelectExpandWrapper instead.

So the result can't be cast to `IEnumerable<Students>`.

For the structure of SelectExpandWrapper, you can refer to https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24select%20and%20%24expand%20support